# Set input text box font size equal to input text box height

Tags: html, css, font-size

Okay I basically have a `.search_bar_container` class that looks like below:

```css
#search_bar_container{
    width: 81%;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45%;
    left: 13.3%;
    height: 10%;
}
```

And a `.search_bar` class:

```css
#search_bar{
    width: 80%;
    height: 99%;
    font-family: cursive;
    font-size: vh;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px black;
}
```

Next my HTML looks like this

```
<div id='search_bar_container'><input id='search_bar'/></div>
```

**THE QUESTION**
My question to you is how do I set the font-size of the search bar equal to the height of the search_bar? Things I have tried so far:
100%...Hmmm I have no idea why this never works for setting font size relative to the text box.
100vh...sets the size to 100% of body...Any way I can change the viewport and set it to the search_bar container...?

Comment: For those browsers that don't support `vh`/`vw` units (including, it seems, Chromium 18/Ubuntu 11.04... *sigh*) would a JavaScript fall-back be acceptable, or does this have to be purely-CSS (and therefore imperfect among unsupporting browsers).

Comment: Javascript is fine. What do you recommend?

Comment: Not sure, yet; I was surprised at Chromium's fail and investigating how to switch to the beta/unstable nightly/dev branches. So, um, haven't really looked into it yet. I'm assuming that you want the font-size to be 9.9% (ish) of the viewport height?

Comment: I just want the font size to equal 95% of the height of the text box..Actually I do not care if the webpage is zoomed in or not. I just want to be able to set the font size at load time.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late but I want to share my solution with you. I use JavaScript to change input font when page loads and when page is being resized. Set `font-size` to `offsetHeight` of input. Then font size will be equal to input height. I think text won't fit then, that's why I use 70% of height like this:

```js
//when window changes its size, make text fit again
window.onresize = function(event) {
    document.getElementById("username").style.fontSize = (document.getElementById("username").offsetHeight*0.7) + "px";
    document.getElementById("password").style.fontSize = (document.getElementById("password").offsetHeight*0.7) + "px";
};

//when page loads make text fit text box
function myFunction(){
document.getElementById("username").style.fontSize = (document.getElementById("username").offsetHeight*0.7) + "px";
document.getElementById("password").style.fontSize = (document.getElementById("password").offsetHeight*0.7) + "px";
}
```

```css
#username{
width:85%;
height:100px;
font-size:25px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
}

#password{
width:85%;
height:50px;
font-size:25px;
padding-left:20px;
padding-right:20px;
}

body{
text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body onload="myFunction()">
<p><input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Username"/></p>
<p><input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/></p>
</body>
</html>
```

If you want to set font size to more or less than 70% of input height, change 0.7 to number you want.